# ao clicar no link fecha o menu toggle

Tags: menu, link, toggle

Olá!

Eu criei um menu em uma pagina que contem ancoras nos links, que levam a um determinado local da página ao ser clicado e ele esta funcionando bonitinho.

Quando visualizo o site em uma tela menor, a nav é substituída pelo botão hamburguer que mostrará os links do menu quando o hamburgue for clicado, até aqui- ok, funciona certinho também.

Quando o hamburguer é clicado, o menu é aberto expondo os links, que ficam por cima de todo o conteúdo do site o que é esperado e normal, mas eu quero que esse menu seja "desativado" quando algum item do menu for clicado.

Por exemplo: Se alguém clicar em sobre, além da tela rolar até a sessão"sobre", eu quero que o menu seja recolhido e fique apenas o botão hamburguer novamente esperando ser clicado outra vez.

Esse é o meu menu:
https://codepen.io/daisy-brazil/pen/qLGpPm

Se alguém puder ajudar eu ficarei muito grata.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vc tem que colocar o evento de toggleClass quando clica no item do menu também... Basicamente o mesmo script que vc usa no Btn Hamburger vc tem que usar quando clica em algum link do menu.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

**Código referente a imagem acima::**

***Deixei o comentário no código onde fiz o script***

```js
 var topOffset = 0;
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(window).scroll(function(){
    $('nav').toggleClass('nav-up', $(window).scrollTop() > topOffset);
    topOffset = $(window).scrollTop();
  });
});


$( ".hamburger" ).click(function() {
    $(".hamburger").toggleClass("is-active");
    $( ".navbar__menu" ).toggleClass( "navbar__menu--active" );
});





$("a").click(function() {
    $(".hamburger").removeClass("active");
    $("#toggle").removeClass("on");
});

//script que fecha o menu quando clica no item

$( ".navbar__link" ).click(function() {
    $(".hamburger").toggleClass("is-active");
    $( ".navbar__menu" ).toggleClass( "navbar__menu--active" );
});
```

```css
/*=======================
 HEADER gi2 
=======================*/
.hamburger {
   float:right;
    padding: 5px 0;
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition-property: opacity, filter;
    transition-duration: 0.15s;
    transition-timing-function: linear;
    font: inherit;
    color: inherit;
    text-transform: none;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 0;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: visible; }
    .hamburger.is-active .hamburger-inner,
    .hamburger.is-active .hamburger-inner::before,
    .hamburger.is-active .hamburger-inner::after {
      background-color: rgba(245, 241, 234, 1); }
  
  .hamburger-box {  
    width: 40px;
    height: 24px;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative; }
  
  .hamburger-inner {
    display: block;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -2px; }

    .hamburger-inner, .hamburger-inner::before, .hamburger-inner::after { float:right;
      width: 40px;
      height: 4px;
      background-color: #FC427B;
      border-radius: 4px;
      position: absolute;
      transition-property: transform;
      transition-duration: 0.15s;
      transition-timing-function: ease; }
    .hamburger-inner::before, .hamburger-inner::after {
      content: "";
      display: block; }
    .hamburger-inner::before {
      top: -10px; }
    .hamburger-inner::after {
      bottom: -10px; }


/*Collapse Transition   X   */
  .hamburger--collapse .hamburger-inner {
    top: auto;
    bottom: 0;
    transition-duration: 0.13s;
    transition-delay: 0.13s;
    transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.55, 0.055, 0.675, 0.19); }

    .hamburger--collapse .hamburger-inner::after { 
      top: -20px;
      transition: top 0.2s 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.33333, 0.66667, 0.66667, 1), opacity 0.1s linear; }

    .hamburger--collapse .hamburger-inner::before {
      transition: top 0.12s 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.33333, 0.66667, 0.66667, 1), transform 0.13s cubic-bezier(0.55, 0.055, 0.675, 0.19); }
  
  .hamburger--collapse.is-active .hamburger-inner {
   background-color: #FC427B;
    transform: translate3d(0, -10px, 0) rotate(-45deg);
    transition-delay: 0.22s;
    transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.61, 0.355, 1); }
    .hamburger--collapse.is-active .hamburger-inner::after {
      top: 0;
      opacity: 0;
      transition: top 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.33333, 0, 0.66667, 0.33333), opacity 0.1s 0.22s linear; }
    .hamburger--collapse.is-active .hamburger-inner::before {
      background-color: #FC427B;
      top: 0;
      transform: rotate(-90deg);
      transition: top 0.1s 0.16s cubic-bezier(0.33333, 0, 0.66667, 0.33333), transform 0.13s 0.25s cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.61, 0.355, 1); }





/*--------------------
menu
--------------------*/
nav { /*--header--*/
    text-align: center;
    color: #e8e8e8;
    display: block;
    background:#e76d80;
    height: 66px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    padding: 20px 0;
    transition: 0.5s;
    width: 100%;
 z-index: 1000;
}

nav.nav-up {
  transform: translateY(-100%);
}



/*--------------------
Mobile
--------------------*/

.navbar {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    max-width: 1250px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    height: 40px;
    padding: 0 15px;
z-index: 10000;
}

.logo {
    margin-right: auto;
}



.navbar__item {
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    line-height: 60px;
}



.navbar__menu{
    background-color: transparent;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: background-color 0s;
}

.navbar__menu a {
    color:#badc58;
}
.navbar__menu a:hover {
    color:#f9ca24;
}





.navbar__menu--active { /*--background transparente--*/
    opacity: 1;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    top: 56px;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    background-color: rgba(22, 22, 22, 0.85);
    transition: background-color .4s; 
margin-top:60px;
}

/*--------------------
Tablet & Desktop
--------------------*/

@media (min-width: 600px) {
    .navbar__menu {
        opacity: 1;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        position: relative;
        top: auto;
        z-index: 1000;
    }
    .navbar__link {
        margin-right: 20px;
        
        color:#EAB543;
    }

    .navbar__link:last-child {
        margin-right: 0;
    }

    .navbar__menu--active {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        justify-content: flex-end;
        position: auto;
        height: auto;
        background: transparent;
    }

    .hamburger {
        display: none;
        padding:6px auto;
    }
}

/* Fim do meu header */
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>slide demo</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 

  
  
<!-- /Menu--><!--gi-->
  
<nav>
<!---->
  <div class='navbar'>
<a class='navbar__item logo' href=''><img src='https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-E9Js5pcqXV0/XCOHvHI4hpI/AAAAAAAADPM/uD-g-Xgk6XUVsl0HuhbehG6wgYshbCydgCLcBGAs/s1600/logo-topo.png'/></a>
           
 <div class='navbar__menu'><!--biel-->
   <a id='ocultar' class='navbar__item navbar__link' href='#1'>Home</a>
   <a class='navbar__item navbar__link' href='#2'>Sobre</a>
   <a class='navbar__item navbar__link' href='#3'>Matérias</a>
   <a class='navbar__item navbar__link' href='#4'>Contato</a>
</div>
          
<span class='hamburger hamburger--collapse navbar__item' id='js-navbar-toggle'>
  <span class='hamburger-box'>
    <span class='hamburger-inner'/>
  </span>
</span>
  </div>  
<!---->
</nav>

<!-- /Menu -->
  
  <div class="container">



<section id='1' style='background:#C4E538; margin-top:120px;'>
  <h1>1</h1>
  <p>
  Far far away, behind the word mountains, far from the countries Vokalia and Consonantia, there live the blind texts. Separated they live in Bookmarksgrove right at the coast of the Semantics, a large language ocean. A small river named Duden flows by their place and supplies it with the necessary regelialia. It is a paradisematic country, in which roasted parts of sentences fly into your mouth. Even the all-powerful Pointing has no control about the blind texts it is an almost unorthographic life One day however a small line of blind text by the name of Lorem Ipsum decided to leave for the far World of Grammar. The Big Oxmox advised her not to do so, because there were thousands of bad Commas, wild Question Marks and devious Semikoli, but the Little Blind Text didn’t listen. She packed her seven versalia, put her initial into the belt and made herself on the way. When she reached the first hills of the Italic Mountains, she had a last view back on the skyline of her hometown Bookmarksgrove, the headline of Alphabet Village and the subline of her own road, the Line Lane. Pityful a rethoric question ran over her cheek, then
    A small river named Duden flows by their place and supplies it with the necessary regelialia. It is a paradisematic country, in which roasted parts of sentences fly into your mouth. Even the all-powerful Pointing has no control about the blind texts it is an almost unorthographic life One day however a small line of blind text by the name of Lorem Ipsum decided to leave for the far World of Grammar. The Big Oxmox advised her not to do so, because there were thousands of bad Commas, wild Question Marks and devious Semikoli, but the Little Blind Text didn’t listen. She packed her seven versalia, put her initial into the belt and made herself on the way. When she reached the first hills of the Italic Mountains, she had a last view back on the skyline of her hometown Bookmarksgrove, the headline of Alphabet Village and the subline of her own road, the Line Lane. Pityful a rethoric question ran over her cheek, then
    A small river named Duden flows by their place and supplies it with the necessary regelialia. It is a paradisematic country, in which roasted parts of sentences fly into your mouth. Even the all-powerful Pointing has no control about the blind texts it is an almost unorthographic life One day however a small line of blind text by the name of Lorem Ipsum decided to leave for the far World of Grammar. The Big Oxmox advised her not to do so, because there were thousands of bad Commas, wild Question Marks and devious Semikoli, but the Little Blind Text didn’t listen. She packed her seven versalia, put her initial into the belt and made herself on the way. When she reached the first hills of the Italic Mountains, she had a last view back on the skyline of her hometown Bookmarksgrove, the headline of Alphabet Village and the subline of her own road, the Line Lane. Pityful a rethoric question ran over her cheek, then
</p>
</section>
  
  
 <section id='2' style='background:#EE5A24;'> 
   <h1>2</h1>
 <p>
  A small river named Duden flows by their place and supplies it with the necessary regelialia. It is a paradisematic country, in which roasted parts of sentences fly into your mouth. Even the all-powerful Pointing has no control about the blind texts it is an almost unorthographic life One day however a small line of blind text by the name of Lorem Ipsum decided to leave for the far World of Grammar. The Big Oxmox advised her not to do so, because there were thousands of bad Commas, wild Question Marks and devious Semikoli, but the Little Blind Text didn’t listen. She packed her seven versalia, put her initial into the belt and made herself on the way. When she reached the first hills of the Italic Mountains, she had a last view back on the skyline of her hometown Bookmarksgrove, the headline of Alphabet Village and the subline of her own road, the Line Lane. Pityful a rethoric question ran over her cheek, then
    A small river named Duden flows by their place and supplies it with the necessary regelialia. It is a paradisematic country, in which roasted parts of sentences fly into your mouth. Even the all-powerful Pointing has no control about the blind texts it is an almost unorthographic life One day however a small line of blind text by the name of Lorem Ipsum decided to leave for the far World of Grammar. The Big Oxmox advised her not to do so, because there were thousands of bad Commas, wild Question Marks and devious Semikoli, but the Little Blind Text didn’t listen. She packed her seven versalia, put her initial into the belt and made herself on the way. When she reached the first hills of the Italic Mountains, she had a last view back on the skyline of her hometown Bookmarksgrove, the headline of Alphabet Village and the subline of her own road, the Line Lane. Pityful a rethoric question ran over her cheek, then
     A small river named Duden flows by their place and supplies it with the necessary regelialia. It is a paradisematic country, in which roasted parts of sentences fly into your mouth. Even the all-powerful Pointing has no control about the blind texts it is an almost unorthographic life One day however a small line of blind text by the name of Lorem Ipsum decided to leave for the far World of Grammar. The Big Oxmox advised her not to do so, because there were thousands of bad Commas, wild Question Marks and devious Semikoli, but the Little Blind Text didn’t listen. She packed her seven versalia, put her initial into the belt and made herself on the way. When she reached the first hills of the Italic Mountains, she had a last view back on the skyline of her hometown Bookmarksgrove, the headline of Alphabet Village and the subline of her own road, the Line Lane. Pityful a rethoric question ran over her cheek, then
</p>
  </section>

  
  
  <section id='3' style='background:#6F1E51;'> 
     <h1>3</h1>
<p>
  Far far away, behind the word mountains, far from the countries Vokalia and Consonantia, there live the blind texts. Separated they live in Bookmarksgrove right at the coast of the Semantics, a large language ocean. A small river named Duden flows by their place and supplies it with the necessary regelialia. It is a paradisematic country, in which roasted parts of sentences fly into your mouth. Even the all-powerful Pointing has no control about the blind texts it is an almost unorthographic life One day however a small line of blind text by the name of Lorem Ipsum decided to leave for the far World of Grammar. The Big Oxmox advised her not to do so, because there were thousands of bad Commas, wild Question Marks and devious Semikoli, but the Little Blind Text didn’t listen. She packed her seven versalia, put her initial into the belt and made herself on the way. When she reached the first hills of the Italic Mountains, she had a last view back on the skyline of her hometown Bookmarksgrove, the headline of Alphabet Village and the subline of her own road, the Line Lane. Pityful a rethoric question ran over her cheek, then
    A small river named Duden flows by their place and supplies it with the necessary regelialia. It is a paradisematic country, in which roasted parts of sentences fly into your mouth. Even the all-powerful Pointing has no control about the blind texts it is an almost unorthographic life One day however a small line of blind text by the name of Lorem Ipsum decided to leave for the far World of Grammar. The Big Oxmox advised her not to do so, because there were thousands of bad Commas, wild Question Marks and devious Semikoli, but the Little Blind Text didn’t listen. She packed her seven versalia, put her initial into the belt and made herself on the way. When she reached the first hills of the Italic Mountains, she had a last view back on the skyline of her hometown Bookmarksgrove, the headline of Alphabet Village and the subline of her own road, the Line Lane. Pityful a rethoric question ran over her cheek, then
    A small river named Duden flows by their place and supplies it with the necessary regelialia. It is a paradisematic country, in which roasted parts of sentences fly into your mouth. Even the all-powerful Pointing has no control about the blind texts it is an almost unorthographic life One day however a small line of blind text by the name of Lorem Ipsum decided to leave for the far World of Grammar. The Big Oxmox advised her not to do so, because there were thousands of bad Commas, wild Question Marks and devious Semikoli, but the Little Blind Text didn’t listen. She packed her seven versalia, put her initial into the belt and made herself on the way. When she reached the first hills of the Italic Mountains, she had a last view back on the skyline of her hometown Bookmarksgrove, the headline of Alphabet Village and the subline of her own road, the Line Lane. Pityful a rethoric question ran over her cheek, then
</p>
  </section>  
    
    
   <section id='4' style='background:#EA2027;'>  
      <h1>4</h1>
 <p>
     A small river named Duden flows by their place and supplies it with the necessary regelialia. It is a paradisematic country, in which roasted parts of sentences fly into your mouth. Even the all-powerful Pointing has no control about the blind texts it is an almost unorthographic life One day however a small line of blind text by the name of Lorem Ipsum decided to leave for the far World of Grammar. The Big Oxmox advised her not to do so, because there were thousands of bad Commas, wild Question Marks and devious Semikoli, but the Little Blind Text didn’t listen. She packed her seven versalia, put her initial into the belt and made herself on the way. When she reached the first hills of the Italic Mountains, she had a last view back on the skyline of her hometown Bookmarksgrove, the headline of Alphabet Village and the subline of her own road, the Line Lane. Pityful a rethoric question ran over her cheek, then
     A small river named Duden flows by their place and supplies it with the necessary regelialia. It is a paradisematic country, in which roasted parts of sentences fly into your mouth. Even the all-powerful Pointing has no control about the blind texts it is an almost unorthographic life One day however a small line of blind text by the name of Lorem Ipsum decided to leave for the far World of Grammar. The Big Oxmox advised her not to do so, because there were thousands of bad Commas, wild Question Marks and devious Semikoli, but the Little Blind Text didn’t listen. She packed her seven versalia, put her initial into the belt and made herself on the way. When she reached the first hills of the Italic Mountains, she had a last view back on the skyline of her hometown Bookmarksgrove, the headline of Alphabet Village and the subline of her own road, the Line Lane. Pityful a rethoric question ran over her cheek, then
  A small river named Duden flows by their place and supplies it with the necessary regelialia. It is a paradisematic country, in which roasted parts of sentences fly into your mouth. Even the all-powerful Pointing has no control about the blind texts it is an almost unorthographic life One day however a small line of blind text by the name of Lorem Ipsum decided to leave for the far World of Grammar. The Big Oxmox advised her not to do so, because there were thousands of bad Commas, wild Question Marks and devious Semikoli, but the Little Blind Text didn’t listen. She packed her seven versalia, put her initial into the belt and made herself on the way. When she reached the first hills of the Italic Mountains, she had a last view back on the skyline of her hometown Bookmarksgrove, the headline of Alphabet Village and the subline of her own road, the Line Lane. Pityful a rethoric question ran over her cheek, then
  
</p>
   </section> 
   


</div>
  
  
  
  
  
  
  <a id="toggle">teste</a>
 

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Muito Obrigado, Funcionou perfeitamente.

Eu já havia tentado esse código  antes, porém, eu estava colocando a classe ".navbar__link" na linha errada. 

Eu estava colocando em na:  $( ".navbar__menu" ).toggleClass( "navbar__menu--active" );, por isso não funcionava.

Fica com DEUS e muito obrigado.

Comment: @EnfermagemObstétrica24Horas que bom que deu certo! Se a minha resposta te ajudou de alguma forma considere marca-la como Aceita, nesse ícone ✔ abaixo das setinhas no lado esquerdo da minha resposta :) assim o site não fica com perguntas abertas pendentes mesmo já tendo sido resolvidas.